# How to load the pages using PhantomJS

Tags: phantomjs

I'm new to Phantomjs.I have tried to load the page using the below code.But the given page is not loading while running this.

```
  console.log('Loading a web page');
  var page = require('webpage').create();
  var url = 'http://www.phantomjs.org/';
  page.open(url, function (status) {
     //Page is loaded!
      phantom.exit();
  });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code is correct but you have to do something before `phantom.exit();`

See all examples [here](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/tree/master/examples).
Let's capture a web page as a screenshot :

```
console.log('Loading a web page');
var page = require('webpage').create();
var url = 'http://www.phantomjs.org/';
page.open(url, function (status) {
    //Page is loaded!
    page.render('phantomjs.png');
    phantom.exit();
});
```